# Navigation with onClick / Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, onclick

I have created a menu for my website which you can find here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nq9Nt/9/

When click a category on the menu it opens that category on my main navigation?

Is something conflicting or have I placed my Javascript in the wrong place?

So I want to be able to click a category and show the sub-categories but it just won't work. Also is there a way to keep open the category you clicked after you change page?

Thank you

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Category 1</a>

</li>
<li class="drop"><a href="#">Category 2</a>

    <ul id="sub1">
        <li><a href="#">Item</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="drop"><a href="#">Category 3</a>

    <ul id="sub1">
        <li><a href="#">Sticker</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sticker</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Category 4</a>

    <ul id="sub1">
        <li><a href="#"> Mural</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mural</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
         $(".drop")
         .on('click', function () {
         $(this).find('ul').toggle();
          })
```

Comment: "So I want to be able to click a category and show the sub-categories but it just won't work" It works on your jsfiddle

Comment: Works for me (or at least seems to be doing what I would expect), what  browser are you using?

Comment: It works for me too, sorry I wasn't clear.

When I add it to my site it doesn't work! Where could I place that code, I'm new to using Javascript so not 100& sure where I would place it?

Also I'm using Chrome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually at least on jsfriddle animation works and if you replace href of your anchors from '#' to a real url you will be redirected to another page, so first make sure that you've attached jquery library in head of the document (since you use it in your script), then move your script to the bottom of the page, right before tag 'body' closes.

About keeping the state of the opened categories after refresh - usually it is made on server side while generating template by adding class, for example 'active', to current link and then, using css, corresponding category (or a hierarchy of categories) is set to be opened (li.active ul {display: block;} for example). Well, actually you could do the same trick - use js to find out current url with the help of window.location.pathname value and match it with a href value of your navigation links and then assign class 'active' to the found element (or its parent, it is up to your css)

Comment: I thought it would be something this simple :)

Thank you so much, just had to add the jQuery script from Google API and placed it at the bottom of my page. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class `drop` to `li` in 4th Category, so it will work as others. And remove that `onclick` if you don't plan to use it.

http://jsfiddle.net/nq9Nt/10/

Comment: Sorry, I was meant to remove that before posting. It's just when placed into my site the Javascript doesn't work.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here the example,

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OZIxUmAL/1/edit)

You have gave the `anchor href` with `#`, So It reloads the page. And also you have gave the `onclick` method, But it doesn't there.